# Referencing Static Functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

For an object in MATLAB, is it possible to call a static function of the same type without knowing the encompassing package? Right now, the only way I've found to reference it is to use `Package.Whatever.staticfunction()`, but I'd like to properly encapsulate the class by having it operate independent of whatever package it's in.

The solution I've found right now is:

```
classdef Whatever
    methods(Static)
        function fig = staticfunction()
             ...snip...
        end
    end
    methods
        function obj = Whatever()
            % Call Package.Whatever.staticfunction();
            eval(sprintf('%s.staticfunction();', class(obj)));
        end
    end
end
```

but this seems clunky, slow, and incorrect. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the instance to call the static method. This looks like a non-static method call, but it's not:

```
classdef StaticTest

    methods (Static)        
        function doStatic()
            fprintf('Static!\n');
        end
    end

    methods
        function obj = StaticTest()
            obj.doStatic()
        end

        function obj = doNotStatic(obj)
            fprintf('Not static!\n');
            obj.doStatic();
        end
    end

end
```

Usage:

```
>> x = StaticTest();
Static!
>> x.doNotStatic();
Not static!
Static!
```

Comment: That's a really strange language decision, but it looks like it worked, thanks!